How to maintain multiple implementations without changing the client code
I am reading Sedgewick's book on algorithms. In the chapter regarding Abstract Data Types (ADT), they defined two different date datatype implementations, one which takes more space, but less compute time, other saving space, but takes more compute time to provide the same results.
class Date {
    private final int month;
    private final int day;
    private final int year;

    public BasicDate(int m, int d, int y) { //constructor
        this.month = m;
        this.day = d;
        this.year = y;
    }

    public int month() {
        return month;
    }
    public int day() {
        return day;
    }
    public int year() {
        return year;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return month() + "/" + day() + "/" + year();
    }
}

And the second implementation with more compute cycles, but less memory needs :
class Date{
    private final int value;

    public SmallDate(int m, int d, int y) {
        this.value = y*512 + m*32 + d;
    }

    public int month() {
        return (value / 32) % 16 ;
    }
    public int day() {
        return value % 32 ;
    }   
    public int year() {
        return value / 512 ; 
    }

    public String toString() {
        return month() + "/" + day() + "/" + year(); 
    }
}

And then they say this :  Java has various advanced language mechanisms for maintaining multiple implementations without needing to change client code, but we use them sparingly
because their use is challenging (and even controversial) even for experts, especially in
conjunction with other advanced language features that we do value (generics and iterators).
What are those features? And how can I maintain these two implementations simultaneously?

I suspect the “advanced mechanism” is SPI jars.  Usually the ServiceLoader class is used to make use of SPI jars.  I suppose before the introduction of ServiceLoader, one could have said “their use is challenging.”  The book is old, so the authors may not have been aware of the ServiceLoader class when they wrote that.

Keeping the client code unchanged is sometimes obtained with the Abstract Factory design pattern, which is nothing special to Java but used with most object-oriented languages. It cannot completely solve the problem, but it moves it somewhere else. Someone has got to decide which concrete factory the client gets when t obtains the abstract factory, but the decision can be taken away from client code, which is therefore completely unchanged.

It’s a joke but with some truth to it: How To Build A Horse With Programming [Comic] describes Java programming as: You really want to build a horse, but first you need to build a horse factory.

I'm not sure what's controversial here but there is a OOP paradigm just for scenarios like this.

Program to an interface not to an implementation, so that the
implementation can change independent to the interface.

Essentially an interface is created in Java, and the concrete classes implement this interface. For this particular case
A MyDate Interface
public interface MyDate {
    public int month();
    public int day();
    public int year();
}

public class BasicDate implements MyDate {
... // code
}

public class SmallDate implements MyDate {
.... //code
}

And then in the Client, it would look something like
MyDate myDateObj = new BasicDate(....); // Notice the type of myDateObj

Now since myDateObj is of type MyDate you could essentially swap it with another object, like so
myDateObj = new SmallDate(...) // works because both classes correctly implement MyDate Interface

Now if you want to create another implementation, the same step follows.
class NewDateImpl implements MyDate {
....
}

And you could then swap out the implementation
myDateObj = new NewDateImpl(...)

The above approach of swapping implementations would not have been possible if the myDateObj was a concrete type
BasicDate myDateObj = new BasicDate(....); // Notice concrete type object
myDateObj = new SmallDate(...); // Complie  time error

All these concepts come under Object Oriented Programming/Design and Design Patterns, there are various books and sites online that discussion these topics in much greater details.
Especially the factory pattern which is also related to the question.

Thats not the point the writers of the book are making. You have to change the original Date implementation into SmallDate and BasicDate. They are saying you don't have to. You can keep both as Date, and there are advanced java mechanisms to achieve that. But they don't go into the details of what those mechanisms are.

In the book they themselves mention the need to create a new class For example, if we were to develop a new implementation ExtraSmallDate, then our only options are to change client code or to make it the reference implementation for use by all clients, just before the paragraph mentioned in the question

Exactly. We have to change the client code for keeping two different implementations. But what is the way to NOT do that, ie keep the two different implementations without changing the client code

@DietzscheNostoevsky Are you experting that your Java program will use a different implementation without you changing the code at all? By magic? Well, you can through reflection if you store the name of the implementing class in a text file and don’t call it “code”, or you have the user enter it on runtime. Personally I don’t take ‘without changing client code so literally ’that we can’t change the instantiation.

@Balaji for the sake of completeness, originally the term “Program to an interface” referred to the abstract idea of an interface, not to a concrete thing such as an interface in Java (which had not been invented yet at the time). So if in a version 2 of my library I change the implementation of Date and you have programmed to the interface, that is, the public methods, then your code still works after the implementation has changed. Even though there is no Java interface in play.
